# TFS 2012: Is it possible to restart a Build Agent programmatically?

Tags: powershell, tfs

I'm looking for the way to restart `build agent` with `powershell` script. If anyone knows the way in `c#` that's fine I can translate.

I know I can easily restart `Build Service` with two lines of code.

Pointing me in right direction is all I need.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to programmatically restart the 2012 build agent.  If your build agent is set to autostart you could reboot the box using PowerShell.

Comment: Restarting Build Service is easier. And I just found IBuildServiceHost.SetBuildAgentStatus Method which may work. I will not know until next week.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to do this via TFS API. SetBuildAgentStatus is used to set the build agent status to following: Available, Offline and Unavailable.

Comment: but that doesn't do anything. make so difference whatsoever. Enabling and disabling it with api at least stop queuing new builds to that agent/controller